# Select layer by attribute - SQL command pending on two columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql

I have a layer, with two columns called NAME and TYPE. 
A polygon in the layer has only one NAME, but can contain multiple TYPE of vegetation.
I want to select different Types of vegetation, where the name is the same.

Example:

[image]

I want to select all the polygons that contain Evergreen AND Dipterocarp.

From the pic the polygon named Doi chiang dao should be selected.

I have tried using the "Select Layer by Attribute" in ArcMap, but I cannot figure out how to create an SQL statement that can do the above-mentioned operation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there is a shorter method, but here is what I would do:
1. "Select by Attributes" to select TYPE = Evergreen OR TYPE = Dipterocarp.
2. Open up attribute table to the newly selected features and right click NAME and summarize over the name. This will create a new table for you that count up how many times NAME occurs in your selection.
Each column with NAME_cnt = 2 will be polygons with both Evergreen and Dipterocarp as TYPES.